# Vue 2.0 Laravel 5.3 Parent Child relationship with slot

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I have a project where when i click on a anchor on parent item-sorting-list a property of child item-card will change so it sort something out based on that property. However the data does not seem to pass to the child. I am wondering if there is anything wrong when i built up the parent child relationship in the meanwhile?

template (item-sorting-list)

```
 <a :name="subcat.name" href="" @click.prevent="getSelectedSubcat(subcat.name)">{{subcat.name}}</a>
```

methods (item-sorting-list)

```
methods: {

      getSelectedSubcat(subcat){
        var vm = this;
        vm.selectedSubcat = subcat
      }
    }
```

When I click on the `subcat.name`, it does actually store `subcat.name` into `selectedSubcat` (verified from Vue devtool) in the `item-sorting-list` component. The problem is `item-card` does not store it even though i put `selectedSubcat` as props

HTML (does this work as parent child relationship here?)

```
<item-sorting-list><item-card></item-card></item-sorting-list>
```

**UPDATED** item-card

```
export default {
    props:[
      'selectedSubcat'
    ],
    data(){
      return {
        products:[],
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getAllProducts()
    },
    methods: {
      getAllProducts(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.$http.get('/getProducts').then((response)=>{
          vm.products = response.data.data.products;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

from Vue devtool, item-card is included in the `item-sorting-list`, I would say that means they are parent child relationship? but then when i click something in `item-sorting-list` and change `selectedSubcat`, `selectedSubcat` in `item-sorting-list` does change but the `selectedSubcat` in `item-card` remains undefined. Sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE2**

I notice that every example that I found online is that they set `selectedSubcat` in the `new Vue` with `el="#app"` in it instead of any other component (in my case `item-sorting-list`). Does that matter? I feel like the `:selected-subcat="selectedSubcat` in

```
<item-sorting-list>
   <item-card :selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"></item-card>
</item-sorting-list>
```

cannot read the `selectedSubcat` that I defined in the component `item-sorting-list` but instead if i set `selectedSubcat` in the following

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
      selectedSubcat:1
    }
});
```

it does read `selectedSubcat` as 1. So what I would say is that `item-card` does not consider `item-sorting-list` as its parent. But why and how can I make it to become `item-card`'s parent? [**NOTE**: but in the Vue devtool the tree does show that `item-sorting-list` does consist of `item-card`, `item-card` does show after clicking the arrow on the left of `item-sorting-list`]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VueJs, you have [parent child relation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration), when you don't register a vue component globally, but you make a component available only in the scope of another instance/component by registering it with the components instance option, like following:

```
var Child = {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
}
new Vue({
  // ...
  components: {
    // <my-component> will only be available in parent's template
    'my-component': Child
  }
})
```

In your case, I dont see `selectedSubcat` being passed as [dynamic props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props) to child component `item-card`. Dynamic props to data on the parent ensures whenever the data is updated in the parent, it will also flow down to the child:

You probably have to pass it to child like following:

```
<item-sorting-list>
   <item-card :selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"></item-card>
</item-sorting-list>
```

You also have to add props in your `item-list` like this:

```
var itemList = {
  props: ["selectedSubcat"]
  template: '<div>Yout component!</div>'
}
```

notice I have converted it to kebab-case, because HTML being case-insensitive, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents([Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried to bind as you did. but got a Vue warn 'Property or method "selectedSubcat" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)' I should my props as 'selectedSubcat' right? or what would be the possible problem here?

Comment: @warmjaijai You should have `selectedSubcat ` as [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) in `item-sorting-list`.

Comment: yes i have. but if i pass selectedSubcat to child and doesnt :selected-subcat=selectedSubcat means to set selected-subcat to be the value of selectedSubcat in child? (btw how do you make the wordings in code font in comment?)

Comment: please help senpei

Comment: @warmjaijai when you do: `:selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"` that means you are binding `selectedSubcat` props in child to `selectedSubcat` variable of parent, see detail [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case).

Comment: I kind of understand it now. But when I do this in HTML `<item-sorting-list><item-card :selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"></item-card></item-sorting-list>` CHILD COMPONENT 
    `props:[
      'selectedSubcat'
    ],`   AND IN THE CHILD COMPONENT TEMPLATE `{{selectedSubcat}}`  it shows warning `vue.js?3de6:515[Vue warn]: Property or method "selectedSubcat" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)` in the console log

Comment: i think it is because of the `:selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"` where the warning disappeared once i deleted it. But it seems nothing wrong to me though. Any thoughts senpei?

Comment: @warmjaijai Have you added `props: ['selectedSubcat'],` in `item-card`, I have also added it in my child component.

Comment: yes indeed. I did add it in my child component `item-card` and I herewith updated my question above for the whole script on my `item-card`. please help check if there is anything wrong with my code. Please life saver senpai

Comment: when i change it to `:selected-subcat="1"`, the `{{selectedSubcat}}` in child does show the value 1. But when i change it to `:selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"` console log shows warn. so what i think is that it does not consider the `selectedSubcat` mentioned here as the same as the `selectedSubcat` that we set in the parent component `item-sorting-list` for some reasons (as I mentioned `selectedSubcat` in parent does change after the click on `subcat.name` in parent but not in child). There must be something wrong but I am not sure.

Comment: @warmjaijai do you have `selectedSubcat` as a data attribute in parent?

Comment: yes I do, here is my data of parent 
   `data(){
      return {
        subcats:[],
        cats:[],
        products:[],
        selectedSubcat:[]
      }
    },`

Comment: Please help to have a look at my UPDATE2 in the post for my conclusion and would you be able to explain why and how should I fix this? Really sorry for my bad English and hope your understanding! Thanks.

Comment: yes this work because the parent component is from the new Vue right. But now I have a parent component `item-sorting-list` wrapping the child component `item-list` and the selectedSubcat is from the parent `item-sorting-list` instead of what you did in there in the new Vue. So I think this makes a difference. But do we always only get props from the new Vue which declares el?

Comment: Thank you so much for so much of your precious time on just this question. I found out that in the `item-sorting-list` compo I would have to set 
      `getSelectedSubcat(subcat){
        var vm = this;
        vm.$root.selectedSubcat = subcat
      }` in stead of 
      `getSelectedSubcat(subcat){
        var vm = this;
        vm.selectedSubcat = subcat
      }` in order to get this work. So `<item-card :selected-subcat="selectedSubcat"></item-card>` does not consider `<item-sorting-list></item-sorting-list>` as its parent but instead the root. Do I always have to set value to root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130296/discussion-between-saurabh-and-warmjaijai).